# Why ndb data memory is 94% if i m using disk storage cluster

Tags: mysql, storage, ndbcluster

I have following structure

2 data node
1 management node
2 sql node

i have create one log file of initial size 200M

then created table space and added 3 data file
data1.dat (initial size: 10GB)
data2.dat (initial size:20GB)
data3.dat (initial size:50GB)

but after inster 10 million record of size around 15 GB its is throwing error of like

table space is full

why this is happening if i am using disk storage for ndb cluster

plz help

Comment: both data node ram is 15GB

Comment: Please provide the actual configuration lines for disk and ram.

Comment: 2 nodes configuration  : 250 GB disk ,15GB RAM